# Dynamic soql picklist binding in WHERE clause

Tags: apex, lightning, aura, dynamic-soql, soql-injection

I have an auraenabled method in my lightning controller apex class. My requirement is that when user selects a picklist value of `status__c` and/or `mode_of_travel__c` as a filter and click on apply then a table of expense records based on the filter should be displayed. The thing is the "if condition" in the where clause' does not seem to be working!

I am getting the following error :

> "System.QueryException: unexpected token: 'Status__c'"

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Expenses__c> findByName(String statuskey,string modekey,list<Expenses__c> explist) {
  List<Expenses__c> results = Database.query('SELECT Id,name FROM 
 Expenses__c where ID in:explist');
 Set<Id> recordIds = (new Map<Id,Expenses__c>(results)).keySet();

 String queryStr= 'SELECT Id, Name, Name__c, Reason__c, Amount__c, 
          Date_of_Expense__c, Status__c,'; 
    queryStr+= 'Mode_of_Travel__c, Category__c, Budget__c, Budget__r.Name,';
       queryStr+='Expense_owner__c, From_Date__c, To_Date__c, isclosed__c,';
        queryStr+='Budget_detail__c, Reimbursed__c FROM Expenses__c WHERE Id 
               IN:recordIds';

         if(statuskey!=null && statuskey!= '' )
         { queryStr+= 'AND Status__c =:statuskey';}

         else if(modekey!=null && modekey!='')
         { queryStr+= 'AND Mode_of_Travel__c =:modekey';}

          List<Expenses__c> e = Database.query( queryStr );

  system.debug('list of final filter exp:'+e);
  return e;
```

Comment: spaces between " AND "  are missing?

Comment: Also - print the query to debug log and post it so we can see if it is ok: `system.debug(queryStr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments said, you're missing a space. For this reason, when I'm building a list of filters, I always use a list of strings, and join them together via String.join.

```
String[] filters = new List<String>('Id = :recordIds');
if(String.isNotBlank(statuskey)) {
    filters.add('Status__c = :statuskey');
}
if(String.isNotBlank(modekey)) {
    filters.add('Mode_of_Travel__c = :modekey');
}
queryStr += ' WHERE ' + String.join(filters, ' AND ');
```

This allows you to easily add or remove filters later, and provides a consistent interface.

Alternatively, consider using fflib_QueryFactory or another pre-built solution so you don't have to keep "reinventing the wheel" each time you need to do something like this.